# My error isn't caught even with try catch

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, exception

I am developing a mobile App with Flutter and Firebase.

I always get the unhandled exception when I try to register with an existing e-mail, although I have surrounded the critical code with `try catch`.

I tested it and the authenticate method is working fine. However, in the other method _submit I am trying to catch my own HTTPException. (The class implements Exception.)

The catch block in submit is doing nothing, not even reacting to any exception. Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier{

Future<void> registrieren(String email, String passwort) async {
    authenticate(email, passwort, 'signUp');
}


Future<void> authenticate(
      String email, String passwort, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=ASASDD';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({
            'password': passwort,
            'email': email,
            'returnSecureToken': true
          }));
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HTTPException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userID = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn']),
        ),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
    _autologout();
    notifyListeners();
}
```

And the method gets executed in this method in another class.

```
Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).registrieren(
        _authData['email'],
        _authData['passwort'],
      );
      print("Registrierung");
    } on HTTPException catch (error) {
      print("Gefangen");
      var message = "Authentifizierung fehlgeschlagen";
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
        message = "E-Mail Adresse wird bereits verwendet";
      }
      if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        message = "Ungültige E-Mail Adresse";
      }
      if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
        message = "Schwaches Passwort";
      }
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        message = "E-Mail Adresse nicht gefunden";
      }
      if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        message = "Falsches Passwort";
      }
      _showError(message);
    } catch (error) {}

    if (_isLoading) {
      CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not awaiting the authenticate call here:

```dart
Future<void> registrieren(String email, String passwort) async {
    authenticate(email, passwort, 'signUp');
}
```

So this function does not wait for authenticate to finish before returning to the register function and thus it cannot catch your exception.

So to fix it add an await or simpy remove the async and return the future from authenticate directly